# IIS7 binding to subdomain causing authentication errors (TFS 2010)

Tags: domain-name-system, iis-7, subdomain, hostname, team-foundation-server

I'm trying to bind a IIS web site (Team Foundation Services 2010) to a subdomain, which is causing authentication errors. First I'll explain what I've done to set it up. This is the fist time I do this, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

The web server is a stand-alone Windows Server 2008 R2 x64, running IIS7 with .NET Framework 4.

I have the following A-records, pointing to my server:

- server.mydomain.com
- *.server.mydomain.com

So all subdomains of server.mydomain.com points to the server. In IIS7 I have a web site (TFS 2010) on port 8080, with a virtual directory (named tfs) that is using Windows Authentication.

I have one binding on the web site pointing to all unassigned IP addresses, port 8080 and having a host name of tfs.server.mydomain.com.

Now, shouldn't I be able to access the virtual directory through:

> http://tfs.server.mydomain.com/tfs

That is not working. However, I can access it through:

> http://tfs.server.mydomain.com:8080/tfs

But, it won't let me authenticate using a Windows account (Server\Username). A windows account that I can authenticate with, when accessing the site through http://localhost:8080/tfs.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Method 2 specified here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861. Do not try method 1 on a production machine.

Comment: This is the answer for me. It fixed external and internal addresses.

Comment: Thank you very much. Method two in the link above, fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this was a typo or not, but as you don't seem to have your site listening on port 80, http://tfs.server.mydomain.com(:80)/tfs will not work.

Regarding authentication - any chance that this box is also a domain controller?

Comment: Okay, so I need the :8080. I was hoping to omit that. But I still have the authentication problem. No, the server is not a DC. It's a stand-alone server, and not even in a domain.

Comment: I would recommend that you enable auditing of logon failures and check the security event log. 

1)start - run - secpol.msc
2)local policies\audit policy
3)audit logon events - success, failure
4)Open an admin cmd prmpot, type gpupdate /force
5) try again (you will fail), run eventvwr, navigate to the security event log, and look at the failures.

Comment: I will try that later today. But what I've noticed is that I can authenticate when accessing http://tfs.server.mydomain.com:8080/tfs from remote (over the internet). Only when accessing the url from the server, it won't let me authenticate.

Comment: See the Method 2 above, it worked for me Tommy.